# Simulate a list of kppm objects in R spatstat

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I would like to use envelope simulation on a list of kppm objects.

I have a point dataset that is in a grid pattern. I would like to shift each point such that its position in the cell is random, then run a spatstat simulation to determine if the points are randomly distributed (obviously will be at sub cell size scale). Then randonly shift shift each point inside the cell, and re-run the simulation - repeating n times and generate an envelope of all the simulations. There are 2 ways to do this 1) using a list of point sets and 2) using simulate.

Method 1) - on a list called my_kppm_list

```
Lmat = envelope(fitM, Lest, nsim = 19, global=FALSE, simulate=my_kppm_list)
plot(Lmat)
```

How to create a list of cluster process models (kppm)?

Naive way:

```
my_list <- list(kppm_0, kppm_1)
```

This fails when trying to run simulation:

```
Lmat = envelope(fitM, Lest, nsim = 19, global=FALSE, simulate=my_list)
```

```
Error in envelopeEngine(X = X, fun = fun, simul = simrecipe, nsim = nsim,  : 
  ‘simulate’ should be an expression, or a list of point patterns of the same kind as X
```

I can convert a list to .ppm

```
fitM_0 <- kppm(create_pts(), ~1, "MatClust")
fitM_1 <- kppm(create_pts(), ~1, "MatClust")
my_list <- list(fitM_0, fitM_1)
ppm_list <- lapply(my_list, as.ppm)
```

But trying to convert to kppm fails with an error

```
kppm_list <- lapply(my_list, as.kppm)
```

Method 2) apply a function in simulation such that a random shift is applied to each point then simulation run, and envelope of all simulations is used (see page 399 of Baddelley et al. Spatial Point Patterns book (2016)):

```
e_rand <- function(){
  j_x <- matrix(unlist(runif(dim(c_df)[1], min=-10, max=10)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
  j_y <- matrix(unlist(runif(dim(c_df)[1], min=-10, max=10)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
  x_j<- c_df[,1]+j_x
  y_j<- c_df[,2]+j_y
  
  c_j <- ppp(x = x_j, y = y_j, window = window)
  return(c_j)
}

Lmat = envelope(fitM, Lest, nsim = 19, global=TRUE, simulate=e_rand)
```

However I found that the null model (red dashed line in output plot) had kinks in it when simulate is added - kinks that do not appear without simulate.

Comment: Your aim is still unclear for me. Please clarify for me. You have a single point pattern of interest that you are studying? Then you want to randomly shift all points of this pattern a number of times so you get a list of point patterns that are just random shifts of the original one? Finally you want to make a simulation envelope of a summary statistic (e.g. L-function) based on the data pattern and the randomly shifted patterns? In that case you do not use a fitted model for anything at all, so I guess I'm misunderstanding what your aim is. Please spell it out very clearly point by point.

Comment: Added a paragraph at the start to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create a list of cluster process models (kppm)?

This is not the problem. In your example you are successfully creating a list of objects of class `kppm`. If `fit1` and `fit2` are fitted models of class `kppm`, then

```
m <- list(fit1, fit2)
```

is a list of objects of class `kppm`.

The problem is that you then pass this list as an argument to the function `envelope` which does not accept this format. The error message from `envelope.ppp` or `envelope.kppm` says that the argument `simulate` must be either a fitted model, or a list of point patterns.

An envelope is constructed by generating simulated point patterns, computing a summary function for each simulated pattern, and computing the upper and lower extremes of these summary functions. The argument `simulate` (if it is given) is a recipe for generating the simulated point patterns. If `simulate` is an expression like `expression(runifpoint(42))` then this expression will be evaluated `nsim` times to produce `nsim` different point patterns. If `simulate` is a fitted model, then `nsim` simulated realisations of the model will be generated. If `simulate` is a list of point patterns, then they will be taken as the simulated random patterns.

It is unclear what you want to do with your list of models.
Do you want to construct a single envelope, or a list of envelopes?

- Option 1: you have a list `m` of models of class `kppm`. For each of these models `m[[i]]`, you want to construct an envelope `e[[i]]`, where the limits are determined`by simulation from` m[[i]]`.
- Option 2: you have a list `m` of models of class `kppm`. For each model `m[[i]]` you want to generate **one** point pattern, say `X[[i]]`, and build an envelope `e` using these patterns.

For option 1, type something like

```
e <- anylapply(m, function(fit) { 
        envelope(Y, Lest, nsim = 19, global=FALSE, simulate=fit)})
```

For option 2,

```
X <- solapply(m, simulate, nsim=1, drop=TRUE)
e <- envelope(Y, Lest, nsim=19, global=FALSE, simulate=X)
```

If you wanted something else, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I have added more detail to the original post - from 'My aim' onwards. NB I tried your code above: > m <- list(fitM_0, fitM_1)
> X <- solapply(m, simulate, nsim=1)
Error in (function (..., check = TRUE, promote = TRUE, demote = FALSE,  : 
  Some arguments of solist() are not 2D spatial objects
> class(fitM_0)
[1] "kppm" "list"

Comment: The command `solapply()` can be replaced by `anylapply()` and then it should work. I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry @EgeRubak that's not it. It should be `solapply` with added argument `drop=TRUE`. I have edited the answer again.